# SQL Server 2005 Includes on a PK Nonclustered Index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to add some includes on my nonclustered PK index in SQL Server 2005, but SSMS doesn't let me. What are good alternatives?

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: could you show the create script for your index please?

Comment: @DForck42, @JNK - Might be more useful if you provided a create script that you think would do this. p.315 of the "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Internals" book explicitly states it is not possible...

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to add `included` columns to indexes backing up PK constraints (possibly because the PK is a logical construct and it is an implementation detail that it happens to be backed up by an index?)

You can just create your own non clustered unique index though instead of using a PK. Foreign keys will still be able to reference it.